# DIV height too great over fixed background image

Tags: css

I am creating a sort of text-slide presentation in HTML. The basic layout is a full-screen fixed background image with text in a centered full-height column in front of it. The basic HTML structure is quite simple:

```
<body>
    <div>
         <h1>Test</h1>
         Text.
         <br />
         <br />
         Text.
    </div>
</body>
```

Setting this up is not difficult, except for one thing: In order for the text-containing div to appear the full height of the window, the height of all three main elements--the html, body, and the div--must be set to 100%. I'm not sure if I'm interpreting what happens correctly, but it seems to result in a situation where any margin or padding on elements within the div are added to the div's height *after* the div has already been expanded to 100% of the height of the viewport. Thus, even though the actual content of the div is less than the height of the window, its calculated height is greater than the height of the viewport, and a vertical scrollbar results, even for minimal content.

What am I missing here?

CSS code is below, please check out this fiddle to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/NL4gg/3/

[I have so far tested this in webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari); if you don't see the issue I've described in the fiddle, that may be why.]

```
html {
    height:100%;
}

body { 
    color: #000;
    background: url(https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8173/8038716643_270547eb16_o.jpg) no-repeat fixed center center;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
}

div {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    height:100%;
    padding:1em;
}
```

Note: This may be the same question asked, but not answered, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545260/why-does-my-content-on-my-website-goes-over-my-body).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/kuj2p/1/)

Add

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Applying that to all elements seems too radical. Also, you might want the `-moz` vendor for support on FF.

Comment: True, but if he's just going to create a simple slideshow presentation using HTML then it shouldn't impact anything much. To be fair, having `box-sizing` set to `border-box` isn't such a bad thing to use going forward. Link [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

Comment: Yea, I have actually read that article, but I disagree, it's similar to `*{margin:0}` It does solve the problem though +1.

Comment: Thanks, kei. That fixed my problem. I hadn't been aware of `box-sizing`, so this has been very useful!

Comment: I spoke too soon: This does indeed fix the problem for situations like the one I posted about where there isn't enough content in the div to overflow the height of the page. But in cases where the content does require scrolling, the div doesn't extend as far as it should.  See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NL4gg/4/

Comment: Figured it out--using `min-height:100%` on the content div is what's needed. Final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NL4gg/5/